# Image file size turned to 17B when upload the photo to Azure Storage Explorer (Ionic 5)

Tags: android, typescript, azure, ionic-framework, blob

I wanted to create a function which able user to upload photo to the azure storage using their mobile device. However, when i run the ionic project, i'm able to capture image and upload to the azure storage but once i upload the image the file size being compressed to 17B which i feel that it get the file name length but not the full size of the image. Please HELP!!!! azure storage output able to view below this thread post. Thanks.

Below Code is the function of capture and upload to azure

```
  capture() {
    this.pickImage(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
  }

  pickImage(sourceType: PictureSourceType) {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: sourceType,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation: true
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(imageData).then((entry: FileEntry) => {
        entry.file(async file => {
          console.log('success get the picture ', file.name, file.size, file.type)
          this.upload(file);

        });
      });
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('this is error message', err)
    });

  }

  async upload(file: File ) {

    console.log('starting upload ')
    console.log('this is imageFile ', file.name)
    console.log('this is imageSize ', file.size)

    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(this.global.blobUrl + this.captureService.containerName + this.captureService.sas); 
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient('test-result');
    const blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(file.name);
    const response = await blobClient.upload(file.name, file.size, {
      blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: file.type }
    }); 
    console.log('this is response status ', response._response.status);

  }
```

[image: Image File compressed to 17B]

Comment: Download the file. Change extension to .txt. Open it and see if it contains file name. Ii think you are right.

Comment: This is correct. Please see documentation for [`upload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#upload_HttpRequestBody__number__BlockBlobUploadOptions_) method. You're actually setting the file content as file name.

Comment: @blackapps Yeah, my file is correct but my file size is incorrect and I don't have any idea with file size taken by file name length

Comment: @GauravMantri Yeah, the file content actually setting in server but the file size is incorrect and taken by file name length.

Comment: @blackapps I tried to download the picture and get the message 'It looks like we don't support this file' in jpg

Comment: Why all this talking. You should upload the content of the file instead of the file name as you do now. Gaurav already told you to do so 3 hours ago.

Comment: @blackapps after i download the jpg file and change the file extension to txt file, it contain the name of the jpg which is "1623921522974.jpg"